# Once mounted using TrueCrypt, cannot unmount

Tags: 11.04, truecrypt

I have an external HDD and use TrueCrypt for keeping encrypted file containers.
After mounting, whenever I try to dismount a file container (using TrueCrypt 7.0a on Ubuntu 11.04), it just does not happen and I get the following message:

```
device-mapper: remove ioctl failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

Further, if I close TrueCrypt and then try to start it again, it says that TrueCrypt is already running, but I cannot access it from the Unity sidebar (because it is not there).

Also, if I power down my external HDD, the TrueCrypt volume still shows as one of the mounted volumes, but I cannot do anything with it.

Any possible work around? I remember this NOT happening in earlier versions of Ubuntu so I am guessing there is something to do with 11.04.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with 10.10 and with a 100MB encrypted image file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks indeed like a problem in Natty. A work-around exists by unmounting the mount point (usually a directory in `/media/`) and then pressing the *Unmount* button in TrueCrypt. An example of the umount command (`sudo` is required):

```
sudo umount /media/truecrypt1
```

After further investigation, it seems that a NTFS formatted container that was created in Windows is affected.

Output of `file -s` on the mounted stuff:

A 99MB volume formatted NTFS which is causing issues:

> /dev/mapper/truecrypt1: x86 boot sector, code offset 0x52, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, reserved sectors 0, Media descriptor 0xf8, heads 1, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80)

A 99MB volume formatted FAT which works fine:

> /dev/mapper/truecrypt1: x86 boot sector, code offset 0x3c, OEM-ID "MSDOS5.0", sectors/cluster 2, reserved sectors 36, Media descriptor 0xf8, heads 1, sectors 204288 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 798, serial number 0xf30d2054, unlabeled
>   The output for EXT* filesystems are similar.

Answer (score 3):

There is some process(es) with file(s) on your encrypted container still opened.

You gave us too few info to help you with detailed instructions.

You should use `fuser` and `lsof` to catch the culprit.

*EDIT:*

if e.g. your TrueCrypt mount point is `/media/truecrypt1` you should try:

`fuser -mv /media/truecrypt1` or `sudo fuser -mv /media/truecrypt1`

and

`lsof +c0 /media/truecrypt1` or `sudo lsof +c0 /media/truecrypt1`

Keep note of the offending PID and kill the process trying one of these commands:

```
kill PID
kill -9 PID
sudo kill PID
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Comment: If I only mount it and then try to unmount it (without even accessing the mounted file system to add/remove files), it still does not work. Can you tell me how to use 'fuser' and 'lsof'?

Comment: @zeiger: I've just updated my answer with `fuser` and `lsof` usage info. Hope it helps. If it works please remember to upvote and accept :)

Comment: +1 I wasn't able to dismount my tc partition and this helped. Thanks